# How to set a default value to an destination schema element in BizTalk Map

Tags: biztalk

I have a requirement in BizTalk map, where

1. I will map some elements from source schema to destination schema,where the values will be assigned to destination schema elements based on some condition.
2. If those values are not assigned, i need to send some default value (N/A).
3. My map is not One-to-One so that i can use a scripting functoid and send a default value, on top of that the destination schema is a flat file and in source schema i have to loop a lot.

So can any body give me some suggestion about "How to set a Default value to a Element in Destination schema if nothing is mapped" using BizTalk Map/some setting in schema.

What I have already tried is, I Opened the destination schema for all the elements I have set the value 'N/A' to a property -> "DefaultValue" which was there in the property tab but when nothing is mapped the default value is not coming. Instead the node itself is not created in the Output file.

Please see the Map below for a good understanding

[alt text http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/0131.problem.JPG](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/0131.problem.JPG)

Source Schema is a XML schema.

Destination Schema is a Flat file schema.

Now in the above map, in my source schema I am having a node called F4706 which will loop.

1. When the element "TypeAddressNumber" within the F4706 is "1", then I am mapping the remaining fields of that F4706 instance to "ship to" details in my destination schema
2. When the element "TypeAddressNumber" within the F4706 is "2",then I am mapping the remaining fields of that F4706 instance to "Reseller" details in my destination schema
3. When the element "TypeAddressNumber" within the F4706 is "3",then I am mapping the remaining fields of that F4706 instance to "EndUser" details in my destination schema

Now if I connect a Logical NOT functoid to the Logical Equal functoid and assign some default value, then the my destination node occurs Three times as one time the "=" functiod returns true one time and false other two times. But what I want is, if anything is there to  map then map from "F4706" instance or assign the default value.

Find the INPUT File below

[alt text http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/5430.ip.JPG](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/5430.ip.JPG)

The output I'm expecting and getting is :

[alt text http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/0724.curOP.JPG](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/0724.curOP.JPG)

Now if the Input file is like below :

[alt text http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/6403.otherIP.JPG](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/6403.otherIP.JPG)

That is when I don't have a "F4706" node with TypeAddressNumber=2, I need to fill "N/A" in Reseller related nodes in my destination schema, which should look like below :

[alt text http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/0435.nextOP.JPG](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/13/0435.nextOP.JPG)

If you go and check the XLST which is getting generated, it is writing a xsl:foreach so if you use xsl:choose/otherwise conditions gets checked multiple times and my output nodes gets duplicated.

I also tried to use some global variable in XLST in First Loop and and second loop to access that and write the default value, unfortunately it doesn't work too. Because a VARIABLE in XLST is not a TRUE variable. I think its a CONSTANT.

How to accomplish this ANY help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put two "Value mapping" (Label them "Incoming" and "Default") on the map and drag the output from both to your destination (you will get a warning at compile time).
2. Put a "Logical NOT" on the map (Label it "NoValue").
3. Put a logical evaluation (Existence, IsNil, Length) that suits your need, to evaluate if you have an incoming value, and drag your source field to it. (Label it "HasValue")
4. Drag the result to the "Incoming" and the "Logical NOT".
5. Drag your source field to the "Incoming".
6. Drag the output from "NoValue" to "Default".
7. Add a constant parameter to "Default", by double clicking and insert new parameter, that is your default value.

Hope you understand this mess :)

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thanks for your response.
unfortunately this wont work for me because

in source schema i have a element which will loop and i have to check for 3 conditions for a single node inside that element, so what happens is that once if condition is true it will assign my incoming value, next two times when it loops the source element, it will fill the default values, resulting in multiple nodes in my destination schema.but i want the destination element to be filled once.

Comment: Hi Santosh,

Do I understand you correctly that you have incoming source looking like:

Root
- LoopingRecord
- - ElementToCheck

If "ElementToCheck" does not fit your 3 conditions you want one (1) destination element to contain "N/A"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are essentially trying to control the creation of an output node based on some condition.

I have tried this for records (you are trying to do this for elements, so I believe this should work for that as well).

I had connected the output of the Logical functoid to the record and the record was created only if the logical functoid returned true.

For default values, you are doing it the right way by putting the default value in the property grid for Schema element. So if nothing is mapped to this element, you will see in the xsl file that the element with the default value is generated.